# Continuing insert from select statement when error occurs

Tags: sql, oracle, error-handling, insert

Can anyone please help me to continue the INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM statement when an error occurs? Thanks in advance.

Sample SQL script is

```
insert into tab1
select id, name from tab2
```

Comment: Can't be done in SQL. The whole point of a SQL statement is that it succeeds or fails as **a single transaction**.  It can be done in PL/SQL using FORALL with SAVE EXCEPTIONS clause. [Find out more](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dml-error-logging-10gr2).

Comment: it depends on an error. if you get a dubkey error, you can use a hint `ignore_row_on_dupkey_index` to ignore that error

Answer (score -1):

if you have a unique key on the target table and you do not have the source table, then it may happen that an error occurs on the insert because of duplicate values

With the hint `ignore_row_on_dupkey_index`, you can ignore the errors.

Here's an example if your table has a Uniq key on the ID. `unique_index_name` is a Name of the uniqueindex on you destination table

```
insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(tab1, unique_index_name) */
  into tab1
( select * from tab2);
```

---

as an alternative, you could look at a merge statement
it might look like this to ignore the errors

```
merge into tab2 a
 using tab1 b
    on (a.id = b.id)
  when not matched then
    insert (id,n)
    values (b.id, b.n)
log errors into ERR$_tab2 REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

;

All errors will be logged into a error table that you have to generate before.
you can do it e.g. like

```
call DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG (dml_table_name  => 'tab2);
```

`ERR$_tab2` will be the error table

Comment: This is a fix for a specific problem which can cause an INSERT statement to abend. I think the OP is after something which can handle a spectrum of errors.

Comment: @APC thats true, i added an alternativ solution with a merge statement to ignore all errors

Answer (score -2):

Please try this.

```
INSERT INTO tab1 (id,name) SELECT id, name from tab2
```

Comment: No idea why somebody upvoted this, it doesn't address the OP's concern at all: *"help me to continuing the insert from select statement when error occurs"*

Comment: Please check in sql it's works fine                                                                         
  insert into tab1 (id,name) select id, name from tab2

Comment: @HemangAghera e.g. this Syntax doesn't work if you  insert dublicate keys and you have a uniq key constraint. Also you Syntax `col1Name(like id),` is not valid or you should explain what you mean

Comment: @hotfix Please check it's Work or not. I was just explaining put your column name.

Comment: It's irrelevant whether it works, **it doesn't answer the OP's question**.